# How are the node threads and tasks managed?

Tags: rpc, substrate-node, runtime-api, tokio

When we run a node, we start a bunch of tasks using `task_manager.spawn_handle()` or `task_manager.spawn_essential_handle()`.

From my understanding, those spawn new Tokio tasks.
If my computer has multiple cores I expect that those tasks run on as many threads as my computer can provide to the Tokio runtime.

I observed that if I spam the node with a lot of RPC calls or a lot of transactions, block production will stop. My understanding is that the node picks its tasks among all available, RPC calls and essential tasks, without prioritizing the essential one.

Another point is that the more concurrent RPC calls I do, the fewer RPCs it handles per second. I would expect different RPC calls to be run in parallel on multiple threads, so the number to go up until we run out of available system threads and then stay stable. It looks like instead they are blocking each other.

Is my understanding of the overall design correct?
How can I make sure that block production is not halted when RPC is under heavy use?
Is there some lock in the RPC execution that makes them so counterproductive to run concurrently ? I'm calling a lot of runtime-api in those RPCs. Those spawn instances of the runtime execution engine. Are those running concurrently or blocking each other?